# Boostrap 3.4 - Arrange multiple buttons in two columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to arrange a few buttons in boostrap 3.4.

I managed to do it (probably by luck) and this is how it looks

[image]

This is the code I used. The idea is to create rows and then various `divs` within the row with the appropriate columns widths `col-xs-N`.

```
<div id="cfd_panel" class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#analysis" href="#collapse2">CFD</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-sm" id='create_cfd_domain' onclick='create_cfd_domain_btn()'>
                    Create/Update Domain
                </button>
            </div>
            <div  class="col-xs-3"  style="padding-right: 1px">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-sm" onclick='map_to_area_btn()' >
                    Airflow Map
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"  style="padding-left: 1px">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-sm" onclick='open_cfd_paraview_btn()' >
                    View
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div  class="col-xs-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-sm" id='mesh_cfd_domain' onclick='openfoam_mesh_btn()'>
                    Mesh 
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-right: 1px">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-sm" onclick='open_cfd_paraview_samples_btn()' >
                    Samples
                </button>
            </div>
            <div  class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 1px">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-sm" onclick='import_from_aws_btn()' >
                    Import
                </button>
            </div>                                    
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div  class="col-xs-3" style="padding-right: 1px">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-sm" id='run_cfd_cases' onclick='openfoam_run_btn()'>
                    Run
                </button>
            </div>
            <div  class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 1px">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-sm" id='sample_cfd_cases' onclick='openfoam_get_results_btn()' >
                    Sample
                </button>
            </div>
            <div  class="col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 10px; ali">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" id='open_cfd_settings' onclick='open_cfd_settings_btn()' >
                    Settings
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" id='open_wind_template' onclick='open_wind_template_btn()' >
                    OFTemplate
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
</div>
```

I am now trying to rearrange the buttons in a different way, but I cannot manage to do it correctly by changing the column widths. This is what happens. The goal is to have MESH and RUN button on the same line and on the first column.

[image]

Is there a proper way to do it?

Comment: If you want the MESH and RUN buttons on the same line, then they need to be contained within the same `row` parent div.  Unless I'm not understanding correctly?   If you place the RUN button in the same `div` that MESH is in, do you get the desired result?

Comment: @DBro they are in the same div. I just did not add the new code.